# @Autowired doesn't work in @Controller in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm getting an error when I'm trying to autowire my Repository in Controller. I've seen this problem by others, but none of the solutions worked for me.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.test.app.repo.TestRepo' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1801) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1357) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at com.example.test.app.MainApplication.main(MainApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]

2022-07-21 17:40:25.777 ERROR 5616 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.test.app.controller.TestController required a bean of type 'com.example.test.app.repo.TestRepo' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.test.app.repo.TestRepo' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 0
```

[My project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dvs5a.png)

POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>test</name>
    <description>test</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
                    <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

MainApplication class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainApplication{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface TestRepo extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {
    Person findById(long id);
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/greet")
public class TestController {
    private TestRepo testRepo;
    @Autowired
    public TestController(TestRepo testRepo) {
        this.testRepo = testRepo;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String greet() {
        return "home";
    }
}
```

Person:

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    public Person() {
    }

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

I tried to add `@ComponentScan("com.example.test.app.repo")` annotation in MainApplication class. Application starts without errors, but mapping doesn't work and I see Whitelabel Error Page and get this in logs:

```
2022-07-21 17:37:03.789 DEBUG 8152 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/greet", parameters={}
2022-07-21 17:37:03.790 DEBUG 8152 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
2022-07-21 17:37:03.802 DEBUG 8152 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Resource not found
2022-07-21 17:37:03.802 DEBUG 8152 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
2022-07-21 17:37:03.802 DEBUG 8152 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}
2022-07-21 17:37:03.803 DEBUG 8152 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2022-07-21 17:37:03.817 DEBUG 8152 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, text/html;q=0.8]
2022-07-21 17:37:03.818 DEBUG 8152 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 404
```

Also tried moving MainApplication in its own package. The error also disappeared, but mapping also didn't work.
`@Qualifier` also didn't help

Comment: Seems like `@Autowired` is working fine. You need to [configure](https://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-data-jpa#:~:text=the%20DAO%20interfaces%3A-,%40EnableJpaRepositories,-(basePackages%20%3D%20%22com.baeldung) your repository correctly.

Comment: If you are using constructor injection, you don't need ```@Autowired```!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that, you have excluded `HikariCP` from your `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`. This means, while doing scanning, spring will try to get implementations of classes for `CrudRepository` which are not having any dependancies of `HikariCP`.

Can you try to configure your repository in your `application.properties` or `application.yml` & then check if you can able to run application properly.

If you have already configured properties, share that so that will update answer based on configuration.

Comment: I tried to delete HikariCP exclusion and it worked! Thanks for giving a hint, I don't know why I put this exclusion

Comment: No worries @KirillGaletskii, glad it worked for you.  you might consider upvoting to answer as well, it will be of good help :-)